# Is there a more optimal way to approach some of these functions?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I completed some bit manipulation exercises out of a textbook recently and have grasped onto some of the core ideas behind manipulating bits firmly. My main concern with making this post is for optimizations to my current code. I get the hunch that there are some functions that I could approach better. Do you have any recommendations for the following code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "funcs.h"

// basically sizeof(int) using bit manipulation
unsigned int int_size(){
    int size = 0;
    for(unsigned int i = ~00u; i > 0; i >>= 1, size++);
    return size;
}

// get a bit at a specific nth index
// index starts with 0 on the most significant bit
unsigned int bit_get(unsigned int data, unsigned int n){
    return (data >> (int_size() - n - 1)) & 1;
}

// set a bit at a specific nth index
// index starts with 0 on the most significant bit
unsigned int bit_set(unsigned int data, unsigned int n){
    return data | (1 << (int_size() - n - 1));
}

// gets the bit width of the data (<32)
unsigned int bit_width(unsigned int data){
    int width = int_size();
    for(; width > 0; width--)
        if((data & (1 << width)) != 0)
            break;
    return width + 1;
}

// print the data contained in an unsigned int
void print_data(unsigned int data){
    printf("%016X = ",data);
    for(int i = 0; i < int_size(); i++)
        printf("%X",bit_get(data,i));
    putchar('\n');
}

// search for pattern in source (where pattern is n wide)
unsigned int bitpat_search(unsigned int source, unsigned int pattern,
        unsigned int n){
    int right = int_size() - n;
    unsigned int mask = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        mask |= 1 << i;
    for(int i = 0; i < right; i++)
        if(((source & (mask << (right - i))) >> (right - i) ^ pattern) == 0)
            return i - bit_width(source);
    return -1;
}

// extract {count} bits from data starting at {start}
unsigned int bitpat_get(unsigned int data, int start, int count){
    if(start < 0 || count < 0 || int_size() <= start || int_size() <= count || bit_width(data) != count)
        return -1;
    unsigned int mask = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        mask |= 1 << i;
    mask <<= int_size() - start - count;
    return (data & mask) >> (int_size() - start - count);
}

// set {count} bits (basically width of {replace}) in {*data} starting at {start}
void bitpat_set(unsigned int *data, unsigned int replace, int start, int count){
    if(start < 0 || count < 0 || int_size() <= start || int_size() <= count || bit_width(replace) != count)
        return;
    unsigned int mask = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        mask |= 1 << i;
    *data = ((*data | (mask << (int_size() - start - count))) & ~(mask << (int_size() - start - count))) | (replace << (int_size() - start - count));
}
```

Comment: Better to post at code review http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

because your int_size() function returns the same value each time you could save some time there:

```
unsigned int int_size(){
    static unsigned int size = 0;
    if (size == 0)
         for(unsigned int i = ~00u; i > 0; i >>= 1, size++);
    return size;
}
```

so it will calculate the value only once.
But replacing all calls of this function by `sizeof(int)*8` would be much better.

Comment: I'd use `sizeof(int)`, but the exercises said to use my `int_size()`, which was another exercise. So, exercise 2 required me write my own `int_size()` function, and the next exercise says to use `int_size()` function for `bit_get()`.

Comment: then you could use my function to eliminate the for loop after the first call

Answer (score 0):

I looked through your code and there's nothing that jumps out at me.

Overall, don't sweat the small stuff.  If the code runs and works fine, no worries.  If you are really concerned about performance, go ahead and run your code through a profiler.

Overall, I will say that the one thing you might be dealing with is the "paranoia" I see in your code regarding the width of an int.  I generally use the fixed-length types in stdint.h and give the caller some options regarding what length of ints (i.e. uint8_t, uint16_t, uint32_t, etc.) they want to deal with.

Also, in C99, there are bitfields, which allow for each bit to be addressed into.

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned int int_size(){

    return __builtin_popcount((unsigned int) -1) / __builtin_popcount((unsigned char) -1);

}
```

This should be faster than looping.

Answer (score -1):

Including int_size() in all the others seems like its going to kill performance unless the compiler is really good at optimizing that loop out.

You could use a uint32_t  instead of an int and then you would know up front the size.

You could also use sizeof(int) to get the size in bytes of an int and multiply by 8.   I haven't seen an environment that defined a byte to be other than 8 bits, but the standard does seem to allow for it in saying it is implementation defined.